# Is async needed when returning a promise?

Tags: javascript, promise

I understand that we use `async` when we want to use `await` inside a function, but if the function returns a promise (without awaiting it), should we prefix the name with async?

Example 1:

```
async function fetching() {
 return fetch('someUrl')
}
```

Example 2:

```
function fetching() {
  return fetch('someUrl');
}
```

What is more proper, example 1 or example 2?

Comment: Where is your `await`? I don't understand what are you trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

`async` and `await` are just convenience methods to work with promises.

```
async function foo(){
    return true;
}
```

is exactly the same as

```
function bar(){
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        resolve(true);
    });
}
```

because `async` encapsulates the return value in a promise, which is resolved, when the method finishes.

In a similiar way

```
async function oof(){
    let myVal = await foo();
    do_something_else();
}
```

(Note: `async` only has to be used here to be able to use `await`)

is the same as

```
function rab(){
    let myVal;
    bar().then(val => myVal = val);
}
```

`await` just makes it easier to chain promises

Answer (score 0):

The result of an `async` function is automatically wrapped in `Promise.resolve`, this means that if you return a Promise, it will be unwrapped automatically. In essence, it does not matter.

```js
const delay = x => new Promise(res => setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("Resolved");
  res();
}, x));

function fetch()
{
  return delay(1000);
}
async function fetchA()
{
  return delay(1000);
}

(async () =>
{
  console.log("Create fetch");
  const f1 = fetch();
  console.log("Await fetch");
  await f1;
  console.log("Awaited fetch");
  
  console.log("Create fetchA");
  const f2 = fetchA();
  console.log("Await fetchA");
  await f2;
  console.log("Awaited fetchA");
})();
```